# View does not Visible if it has nothing to show how?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
  I have a view for ads in my application .
```

if my application has no ads to show then the View  must not be visible
 (no blank space).  how can i do that ??????????

Thanks in advance for your valuable  time time

Regards,
Kariyachan.

Answer (score 2):

yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE) or yourView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)

Comment: @user479211 Thanks for the replay,Sounds great But i need to then how can i listen for whether admob server is sending ads or not  to my application ........any ideas??????

Comment: what data you receive and how?